# Using JavaScript to get the original url of a HTTP redirected page (302)

Tags: javascript, redirect, http-redirect, http-status-code-302, http-referer

I would like to detect (using javascript) if the current page was loaded directly or was loaded after a server redirection (HTTP 302). And if redirected, I would like to get the original url.

I can detect that a redirection occurs with `window.performance.navigation.redirectCount`.

Then I tried to get the original url with window.referrer which is an empty string.

Do you know a way to get this original url?

Thanks

Comment: Is something that you need for production? As much as I know, there's no way to achieve it, for security reasons. In my company we had a similar problem and we ended up asking the back-end developer to return a 200 instead of a 302

Comment: `window.performance` is meant to be used for development only